# Syntax erro in Python

Tags: python

Please what's wrong with my python code. I wonder what could be causing the error, I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
def all_elements_are_the_same(vlist: 'List[Any]') -> bool:
                                   ^
```

This is the completed code

```
def all_elements_are_the_same(vlist: 'List[Any]') -> bool:
    if not vlist:
        return True

    f_val = vlist[0]
    for val in vlist:
        if val != f_val:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Type annotations are a relatively recent addition to the Python language.  What version are you using?

Comment: Even "relatively" is a stretch; they were first added in Python 3.0, over 11 years ago.

Comment: This is only a syntax error in Python 2.7 or earlier.

Comment: You are right @jasonharper. it was a beginner's mistake, I used python app.py but I should have used python3 app.py

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

convert

```
def all_elements_are_the_same(vlist: 'List[Any]') -> bool:
```

to

```
def all_elements_are_the_same(vlist: List[Any]) -> bool:
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a string as an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need type annotation? As others have pointed out this is not supported for Python 2.7 and earlier.

You could simply do

```
def all_elements_are_the_same(vlist):
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, this issue was solved by using Python 3 as originally intended. The currently accepted answer is unrelated to the problem.

Type annotations were not a language feature in Python 2, hence the error.